# ajax code not calling php file, html forms

Tags: php, ajax

```
function show(value) {
    var datastring = 'ptcid='+ value

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "filldropdown.php",
        data: datastring,
        success: function(responseText){$("#ptscid").html(responseText);}, 
        error : function  { (alert("error"); )}
    });
}
```

this is the code of select option which is dependent on another select option

my problem is that filldropdown file is not called. even i checked apache access log, it doesn"t show any access of filldropdown.php file. how to make ajax access it

Comment: if you are in chrome open up developer console and add console.log('calling ajax'); right before ajax call. Does anything show up?

Comment: Actually your code should work. How do you know it is not being called? How do you manipulate things in `filldropdown.php`? Also, add `()` to your error function, it should be: `error: function() { alert('Error'); }`

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
var datastring = 'ptcid='+ value
```

should be

```
var datastring = 'ptcid='+ value;
```

you must have semicolon ; at the end of JS statement.

EDIT:

Also, you must declare function properly in AJAX error

```
error: function(){alert("error");}
```

and you don't need to close alert in () only argument to alert() function.